# Entering different types (in C)

Tags: c

I'm attempting to prompt the user to enter several numbers and, when the user enters a string, the program calculates the sum of those numbers. I'm having difficulty because I want to keep the program as simple as possible without creating other variables to store strings, etc.

```
int menu(int choice){
  int total = 0, values = 0;
  char *string = (char*) &values;
  switch(choice){
    case 1: printf("Enter your values separated by a whitespace: ");
      while(string != "compute") {
        scanf("%d",&values);
        total = total + values;
      }
  }
  return total;
}
```

I want the user to enter as many numbers as s/he wants (obviously within memory limits), so I have to continually anticipate an int (or other "number"), so what's the most effective way to also anticipate a string?

I know that the following line is a bit sketchy, but why exactly if I want the variable "string" to treat "values" like a string/char type?
    `char *string = (char*) &values;`

Comment: That's not how you compare strings.  `man strcmp`

Comment: `string` is pointing to an `int` type, and it will never hold an actual string no matter what the user input to `scanf`. Also, this is not how you test strings in C. By doing `string != "compute"` you are actually comparing pointers.

Comment: To keep it simple, I suggest you use the input 0 as cue to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you write like this

```
int total = 0, values = 0;
char *string = (char*) &values;
```

You set the pointer string to point to the integer value `values` so if the user enters a value that is larger than `sizeof(values)` i.e. sizeof(int), the program will crash.

Instead use a dedicated buffer for the input string

`char string[128] = {0};`

scanf can be used for input but it is safer to use fgets() to minimize the risk of a buffer overrun:

`fgets( string, sizeof(string), stdin );`

if you need to hold the individual values entered declare an array of ints e.g.

`int values[100];`

when the user has enters something check the content of 'string' and see if it
contains compute - it may be enough checking the first char - e.g. `if ( string[0] == 'c' )` else convert the string to int and place it in the array of values:

`values[i++] = atoi(string);`

EDIT:

As McNabb pointed out fgets() adds a \n to the string so if you want to compare the whole string you must take that into account e.g.

```
if ( !strncmp( "compute", string, strlen("compute") ) 
{...}
```

Comment: Would be good to also mention the `\n` issue with `fgets`, as a naive application of `strcmp(string, "compute")` will fail here.

Comment: yes although in this case he may just check the first char of the string and atoi ignores \n but true if there will be more keywords starting with same letter.

Comment: What is a "buffer overrun" in this situation? You already declared a dedicated buffer using char string[128] = {0}. Do you mean in case the input exceeds 128 bytes?

Comment: @fibono it happens when the argument to the function does not correspond to the specified format type i.e. the argument is smaller than the format specifier requires. e.g. scanf( buffer, "%ld", &n ) where n is a char. you would not get a compile error so it may be difficult to see.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method would be to read in a string (use `fgets()`), then try to decide what it is.  If it's an integer, you can use `atoi` or `strtol` to convert it.  If it's a float, you can use `strtod`.  Otherwise, you can parse the string however you want.

So you'll end up with something like this:

```
char str[15];
long sum = 0, val;
char* ptr;
while (1)
{
    fgets(str, 15, stdin);
    if (0 == strcmp(str, "compute"))
    {
        printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
        break;
    }
    val = strtol(str, &ptr, 10);
    // error-check here.
   sum += val;
}
```

Another, simpler option, might be to read integers (using `scanf`, as in your code above) until end-of-file, then print the sum.  That approach has some limitations: you need to give your input through some channel that has a defined EOF, and you can't receive more input after the end of your list of integers.  Use a specific value (such as 0) as a sentinel, as Havenard suggested, does not have these drawbacks, but doesn't allow the sentinel value to appear in your list of numbers either.

Answer (score 0):

To read a string you have to allocate some space for it. You cannot read it into an integer.

To support reading input that could be either an integer or a string, you have to read a string; and then you can try to convert the string to integer.

For example:

```
char buffer[50];
scanf("%49s", buffer);

if ( 0 == strcmp(buffer, "compute") )
    return 0;    // they typed "compute"

if ( 0 == sscanf(buffer, "%d", &number) )
    break;       // they typed something that was not a number

total += number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why are you trying to compare strings at this point.  If you just want to read whitespace separated integers until a non-integer value is entered, let scanf do the work for you:

```
int menu(int choice){
  int total = 0;
  int value;
  switch(choice){
    case 1: printf("Enter your values separated by a whitespace: ");
      while(scanf("%d",&value) > 0) {
        total += value;
      }
  }
  /* Here, use scanf to get the first non-integer value entered */
  return total;
}
```